# Lager text isn't centred in toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, toolbar, title, titlebar

I tried to place the titles of my fragments in centre of the toolbar but one of them is misplaced... I can't figure out why...

The code I used is the next one:

```
     if (appCompatTextView != null) {
                val params: Toolbar.LayoutParams = Toolbar.LayoutParams(Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                appCompatTextView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                appCompatTextView.layoutParams = params
            }
```

The `Home` tab toolbar looks like this:
[image]

And the `Android Studio` tab looks like this:
[image]

**How should I place the `Android Studio` text in center?**

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue when i try to center it with code. So i created an xml file with centered text. I know it's not what you are searching, but it can get the job done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```